# How do I set a value for the default option with Html.DropDownList

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm using ASP MVC RC1.

A form I'm using contains a dropdownlist which I have put in a view with this code.

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("areaid", (SelectList)ViewData["AreaId"], "Select Area Id")%>
```

However, when rendered, this is what I get

```
<select id="areaid" name="areaid">
   <option value="">Select Area Id</option>
   <option value="1">Home</option>
   ...
</select>
```

What I'd like is for the Select Area Id option to have a value of 0 and mark it as selected by default so it is consistent with the other values and I can validate whether or not an area has been chosen as it is a mandatory value. AreaId is an integer so when I currently click the form without touching the dropdownlist at all, MVC complains that "" is not an integer and gives me a binding error.

SO how do I set a value for the default option and then make it selected on the form?

Thanks, Dan

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think you have <strike>three</strike> four options.  First when you are building your SelectList or enumerable of SelectItemList, prepend the selection with your option label and default value.  Putting it at the top will make it the default if some other value isn't already chosen in the model.  Second, you could build the select (and options) "by hand" in the view using a loop to create the options.  Again, prepending your default selection if one isn't supplied in the model.  Third, use the DropDownList extension, but modify the value of the first option using javascript after the page is loaded.

It doesn't seem to be possible to use the DropDownList extension to assign a value to an optionLabel as it is hard-coded to use `string.Empty`.  Below is the relevant code snippet from http://www.codeplex.com/aspnet.

```
    // Make optionLabel the first item that gets rendered.
    if (optionLabel != null) {
        listItemBuilder.AppendLine(ListItemToOption(new SelectListItem() { Text = optionLabel, Value = String.Empty, Selected = false }));
    }
```

**EDIT**: Finally, the best way is to have your model take a Nullable value and mark it as required using the RequiredAttribute.  I would recommend using a view-specific model rather than an entity model for the view.  Since the value is Nullable, the empty string will work fine if posted back without choosing a value.  Setting it as a required value will cause the model validation to fail with an appropriate message that the value is required.  This will allow you to use the DropdownList helper as is.

```
public AreaViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public int? AreaId { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Areas { get; set; }
    ...
}

@Html.DropDownListFor( model => model.AreaId, Model.Areas, "Select Area Id" )
```

Comment: Thank you. I now create a List<SelectListItem> object, insert a default option with value 0 at index 0 and pass that to Html.DropDownList. It works a treat.

Comment: Thanks that helped me as well! It's sad that even with MVC 3 it isn't possible to add the default value :/

Comment: @LanFeusT - this was answered long before MVC3.  I've updated it for a better method of dealing with it from a model perspective, esp. with MVC3.

Comment: @tvanfosson this is the second time a post of yours has helped me thanks.

Answer (score 3):

For MVC3, SelectList has an overload whereby you can define the selected value.

```
Function Create() As ViewResult

        ViewBag.EmployeeId = New SelectList(db.Employees, "Id", "Name", 1)

        Return View()

    End Function
```

In this case, I happen to know that 1 is the id of the default list item I want, but presumably you could select the default via query or what ever floats your boat

Comment: This works great. To answer Dan's question I believe he wants:

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing the default item from the definition in the View, You can add the "Select Area" data at the 0th index of the List from the controller.

This way the Select Area data has an index value of 0.

Comment: Very nice fix for my buggy view where i had 2 dropdowns, one was selecting default okay, second was always not selecting anything whatever i did.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to use the same SelectList for multiple drop downs and didn't want to duplicate the SelectList in the model so I just added a new Html Extension method that took in a value and set the selected item.

```
public static MvcHtmlString DropDownList(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string name, string value, IList<SelectListItem> selectList, object htmlAttributes)
{
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items = selectList.Select(s => new SelectListItem {Text = s.Text, Value = s.Value, Selected = s.Value == value});
    return htmlHelper.DropDownList(name, items, null /* optionLabel */, htmlAttributes);
}
```