# Select from dropdownlist, chosen value create another same value?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, drop-down-menu

I have create dropdown list, with this controller:

```
string tmpUser = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
var kdoseprijavlja = (from dllist in dbContext.UsersTables
                      where dllist.username == tmpUser
                      select dllist.userID).FirstOrDefault();

var seznam = dbContext.CustomerTables.Where(m => m.UserId == kdoseprijavlja).Select(m => m.Customer);
var seznam2 = dbContext.CustomTypes.Where(m => seznam.Contains(m.Id_NewCustomerType)).Select(m => m.CustomerType);
List<string> result = new List<string>();

foreach (var customer in seznam2)
{
   result.Add(customer);
}

ViewBag.DropList = new SelectList(result);
ViewBag.Destination = parameters.Destination;
```

And in View Index I have create this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("destination", ((SelectList)ViewBag.DropList).Select(t => new SelectListItem() { Text = t.Text, Value = t.Text, Selected = (t.Text == ViewBag.Destination) }), "--Select--", Model.Search.Destination)
```

Now this creates this:

[image]

So it do this, when I choose some value, and click for Search (Post) it save value, that I choose, this is fine, But!

**My problem is, that I whant to have dropdownlist without option "--Select--", so first value would be, first value from dropdownlist.** I have done this, I have remove --Select-- from index:

```
@Html.DropDownList("destination", ((SelectList)ViewBag.DropList).Select(t => new SelectListItem() { Text = t.Text, Value = t.Text, Selected = (t.Text == ViewBag.Destination) }), Model.Search.Destination)
```

Removing  --Select-- from code works, but problem is that doubles chosen value, for example if I choose "GMTK" and click Search it do this: (it doubles value)

[image]

Comment: set the first one choosen by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the controller part, You can add selected value in the viewbag.

Look here [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492553(v=vs.118).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492553%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

the value you want to select, must me pass as selectedValue

```
string selectedValue = "GMTK";
ViewBag.DropList = new SelectList(result,"Id","text",selectedValue);
```

Hope, It may help you. Have a nice day. :)

OR correct last part of your DropDownList in Razor:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("destination", ((SelectList)ViewBag.DropList).Select(t => new SelectListItem() { Text = t.Text, Value = t.Text, Selected = (t.Text == ViewBag.Destination) }), (SelectList)ViewBag.DropList)
```

Comment: it will be your id value of GMTK try it

Comment: i have mean, that errors shows if i use your sugestion. selectedValue is underline and says that cannot resolve symbol 'slectedValue'

Comment: what is selectedValue?

Comment: What should "Id","text" stand for, or it is not mather, what you put here? Because in Razor I get this error: DataBinding: 'System.String' does not contain a property with the name 'Id'

Comment: "GMTK" is not default value, it is call from database and it is set as user role, this GMTK is only for this default user that I have tested, other users have diffrent values.

Comment: thats what m saying, the value you want to select, pass it as string. it will get selected

Comment: ok, I think that I have solve it :D, i have done this: ... t.Text == ViewBag.Destination) }), (SelectList)ViewBag.DropList)

Comment: oh thank GOD! finally! :D So, as i didn't answered your question, i cant ask you mark it correct :P hehehe :D Enjoy, have a nice day :)

Comment: can you edit your answer with my answer, I whant to mark it as correct, for my future research It will be easy me to find it. Please.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong, you're trying to take the option label "--Select--" out. 
By looking at the API apparently the option label accept null value. Have you tried something like

```
@Html.DropDownList("destination", ((SelectList)ViewBag.DropList).Select(t => new SelectListItem() { Text = t.Text, Value = t.Text, Selected = (t.Text == ViewBag.Destination) }), "", Model.Search.Destination)
```

or

```
@Html.DropDownList("destination", ((SelectList)ViewBag.DropList).Select(t => new SelectListItem() { Text = t.Text, Value = t.Text, Selected = (t.Text == ViewBag.Destination) }), string.Empty, Model.Search.Destination)
```

I can't test it at work. But the idea is, instead of removing the option label, try to pass down a null value or an empty string and see if the API is going to ignore it or not.

Comment: Thanks for sugestions, yes, I do whant to take out label --Select--, your sugestions wokr, but not as I whant, first value is empty, I whant that first value is first from dropdownlist...

Comment: @geekforfreek Well if that doesn't work you may wanna take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/581805/how-do-i-set-a-value-for-the-default-option-with-html-dropdownlist). They managed to set a value for the option label. So you may define the option label name as your first item name and set its value accordingly.