# Custom select option as the 1st option in a mysql populated dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm populating a dropdown list using a mysql database. Everything works fine. But how do I set the first select option as below?

```
<option value="">......</option>
```

html

```
<select id="from_oq">
</select>
```

jQ

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      var countries="";
      $.getJSON("countries.php",function(data){
        $.each(data,function(index,item){
          countries+="<option value='"+item.id+"'>"+item.fullName+"</option>";
        });
      $("#from_oq").html(countries); 
      });
  });
```

Comment: see [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/581805/how-do-i-set-a-value-for-the-default-option-with-html-dropdownlist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make this:

```
<select id="from_oq">
<option value="-1">Please select an option</option>
</select>
```

and add this in the jQ:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      var countries="";
      $.getJSON("countries.php",function(data){
        $.each(data,function(index,item){
          countries+="<option value='"+item.id+"'>"+item.fullName+"</option>";
        });
      $("#from_oq").html($("#from_oq").html()+countries); //<----- THIS
      });
  });
```

Greetings from Austria

Answer (score 0):

You can directly replace

```
var countries="";
```

to

```
var countries='<option value="-1">Please select an option</option>';
```

to have the same effect in your already existing javascript